# schedule python script using cronjob on macOS using a venv environment

Tags: python-3.x, cron, python-venv

I am using Apple M1 (Monterey OS). I am using a venv environment and Python 3.11.3

This is how my cronjob looks like :

```
5 * * * * . /Users/vanhell/code/StayHydrated/src/venv/bin/python3 /Users/vanhell/code/StayHydrated/src/main.py
```

This doesn't work.